# Delphi XE7 Developing for iOS 7+

Tags: ios, delphi, xcode7, delphi-xe7, macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to compile an app for iOS using Delphi XE7.

I tried to install OSX 10.13 High Sierra and XCode 7.2, but cannot compile under the iOS Simulator, as I get an error that I need to specify a UUID.

But, when I was searching online, someone said that Delphi XE7 only supports up to iOS 7, and XCode 7.2 only has iOS 9+.

So, the main question is, can I compile for iOS 7+ using Delphi XE7? If not, I cannot compile for new iPhones/iPads?

Comment: That's right. You need to pay for the Delphi update.

Comment: Delphi XE7 was released in 2014. Since then there were 4 major iOS releases that usually require changes in the application build process. Mobile platforms, both Android and iOS, with yearly OS releases, are fast moving targets. If you want to develop for mobile you need to keep current. Delphi update subscription is the way to go.

Comment: Up to iOS9 is supported (32-bit only) in XE7.  Embarcadero [has guidance](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/steps-for-building-ios-32-bit-applications-for-ios-9-with-xe7-and-xe8) posted.  The [support matrix](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/PlatformStatus/en/Main_Page) is also available.

Comment: To get support for newer technologies, you need to upgrade to a newer version of the IDE that supports them.

Comment: Ty all for the info, just tried 10.3 Rio and it worked as it should, time to buy some upgrades then I suppose.

Comment: I think upgrades don't exist anymore. You have to buy new licences.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well that will be a bit bad if its like this. Anyway I contacted Embarcadero to see what they can say about upgrading. Ty for the info

Comment: If they sell you an upgrade, do let us know. Because they don't offer upgrades to anybody for the past year.

Comment: Will do when I get a response from them, I wrote the email this morning, so will have to wait for a response.

Comment: P.S Still no response from Embarcadero.....